# How to search content but skip what is inside square brackets?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find all posts that have double quotation mark `"` in `post_content` table

```
SELECT * FROM `pl_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%"%'
```

This is a WordPress website so I get few thousands rows because each post contains shortcodes, most frequently this one:

```
[gallery columns="4" ids="22502,22504,22503"]
```

How can I search for everything in a `post_content` table but so that it skips what is inside square brackets `[...]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several solutions are possible for your `WHERE` clause, depending on your data.

Option 1 : just skip records whose content contains square brackets

```
post_content LIKE '%"%' AND post_content NOT LIKE '%[%'
```

Option 2 : if you have mixed fields content with double quotes oustide AND inside square brackets, a solution is to remove anything inside square brackets before seaching for the double quote

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '\\[[^\\]]*\\]', '') LIKE '%"%'
```

The regexp means : an opening bracket, followed by O to N characters different than a closing bracket, and then a closing bracket.

Option 3 : functionnaly identical to option 2, but using `REGEXP_REPLACE` with a bit more complicated regex :

```
REGEXP_LIKE(txt, '(^|\\])[^\\[\\]]*"')
```

For older versions of MySQL (< 8.0.4), this can be written :

```
txt REGEXP '(^|[[.right-square-bracket.]])[^[.left-square-bracket.][.right-square-bracket.]]*"'
```

**db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32195bddf4fd1b8b2eaf3800f5188c47)**

```
 WITH tests as (
     SELECT '[columns="4"]' txt
     UNION SELECT 'abc"db'
     UNION SELECT 'abc"db[columns="4"]'
     UNION SELECT '[columns="4"]abc"db'
     UNION SELECT '[columns="4"]abc"db[columns="4"]'
 )
 SELECT 
     txt, 
     txt NOT LIKE '%[%', 
     REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '\\[[^\\]]*\\]', '') LIKE '%"%',
     REGEXP_LIKE(txt, '(^|\\])[^\\[\\]]*"')
 FROM tests
```

```
 txt                              | txt NOT LIKE '%[%' | REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '\[[^\]]\]', '') LIKE '%"%'    | REGEXP_LIKE(txt, '(^|\])[^\[\]]"')
 :------------------------------- | -----------------: | --------------------------------------------------: | -------------------------------------:
 [columns="4"]                    |                  0 |                                                   0 |                                      0
 abc"db                           |                  1 |                                                   1 |                                      1
 abc"db[columns="4"]              |                  0 |                                                   1 |                                      1
 [columns="4"]abc"db              |                  0 |                                                   1 |                                      1
 [columns="4"]abc"db[columns="4"] |                  0 |                                                   1 |                                      1
```

Comment: I am not sure how to work with option 2, from searching elsewhere on how to use REGEXP_REPLACE I tried to run: SELECT post_content, REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '\\[[^\\]]*\\]', '') FROM wp_posts - If this is correct, I get FUNCTION REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist

Comment: @IvanTopić, which version of mysql are you using ?

Comment: @IvanTopić : if you are running MySQL < 8.0.4, you need to change the syntax : I updated my answer. This expression should be placed in the `WHERE` clause, like : `SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content REGEXP '(^|\\])[^\\[\\]]*"'`

Comment: Hm now I see that REGEXP_REPLACE needs MySQL 8+. I am doing this on localhost, Wampserver is installed with MySQL 5.7.19. and looking at Wamp website this is the version they mention in downloads section

Comment: Whole query should be: `SELECT post_content  FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content REGEXP '(^|\\])[^\\[\\]]*"'` and that is it? I get no results, but if I place LIKE part after I get error in syntax: `SELECT post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content REGEXP '(^|\\])[^\\[\\]]*"' LIKE '%"%'`

Comment: @IvanTopić : you do not need the `LIKE` part. It's all included in the regex. Can you please try the query that I gave you and let me know if it works ?

Comment: I did, I get `MySQL returned an empty result set`.  I am still testing because if the query is ok hm... there should be some results since I have also just placed a couple of random `"` in some posts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186982/discussion-between-gmb-and-ivan-topic).